# Difference between reality and debug console

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, console.log

I'm totally lost.

Here is my code:

```
    var iframe = $(this.module.parentDocument).find("iframe[data-modulid='" + modulid + "']");
    console.log("iframe", Object.assign(iframe));
    var module = iframe[0].contentDocument.children[0].getAttribute("module");
    console.log("module", Object.assign(module));
```

I get an iframe, and I show it in the console. It appears, and when I look in its contentDocument -> 1st children, I found the `module` attribute I placed here before.

But when I put it in a var and then I show it in the console, it's undefined, it doesn't exist anymore. I can go to the first children, but apparently there is no `module`.

I thought that was because in the console, content is "actualised", so I put my vars in an Object.assign() to be sure there are simple copies. But nothing change...

I someone found something, I marry him/her!

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing it before the iframe has loaded. Use a load event listener

Comment: Did you get any console errors? Could be related to onload event or you don't have access to iframe content

Comment: "*I put my vars in an Object.assign() to be sure there are simple copies.*" - No, that didn't work. The first parameter to `Object.assign` is the target, which is returned unaltered in your case. Maybe you meant `Object.assign({}, iframe})`? But notice that this still might have difficulties with enumerability and ownership of the some of the properties.

Comment: You're right, I tried with `Object.assign({}, iframe})` and then I saw that my iframe wasn't loaded.
Thank's a lot!